# mat dialog is not opening properly if i click on any key then only it is opening

Tags: angular, angular-material, confirmation, mat-dialog

i have used mat dialog for confirmation dialog on cell click of a ag grid table,  earlier popup was working fine but now it is not working if click on any key like tab or shift or alt or any key then it is getting opened properly, other wise it is not opening

```
 onCellClicked: (event: CellClickedEvent) =>
      {  
        this.showDropdown = true;
        this.selectedTicket = event.data;
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent,{
        data:{ 
          showDropdown:true,`your text`
          message:this.traslateService.instant("Pleasechangestatus"),
          event:event,
          dropdownList:this.ticketStatusArray,
          buttonText: {
            ok: this.traslateService.instant("Yes"),
            cancel: this.traslateService.instant("No"),
          }
        },
        panelClass:'confirm-comp'
      })
      // element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key':'Shift'} ));

       dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res=>{
           if(res != "" && res){
                this.confirmchange(res);     
           }
       })
    },
```